# SASS - change value of variable to use it in two classes

Tags: css, variables, sass, mixins

I have been trying to create a variable called like "$active" and then, it depends of the class where we are, it's changing this value. But it doesn't work. Show you the code

```
$active : #000 !default;

.class-1 {
   $active : red;
}
.class-2 {
   $active : green;
}

.class-1, .class-2 {
   color: $active;
}
```

So, in this way, what I though is changing the value depending of the class we are, then, apply this color for the class. The thing is, I have a lot of code under those two classes, I can not assign the color without the comma, otherwise I will repeat to much code.

Also, I discovered something really weird and it can be the key why is not working, in the code, if i write like this:

```
$active : #000 !default;

.class-1 {
   $active : red;
   color : $active; // Here it's working, red!
}
.class-2 {
   $active : green;
   color : $active; // Here it's working, green!
}

.class-1, .class-2 {
   color: $active; // No way to make it works! :(
}
```

Do you have any idea? Any suggestion is welcome, Thanks!

Btw, I already tried with Mixins and functions, but it's the same...

**--- EDIT ---**

I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry. I just created a pen for this example, with comments and everything to try to be clearer. From my point of view, it happen that I am overriding the variable value not in the global context, but not sure if it's like that...

http://codepen.io/ialex90/pen/RaEyWx

Comment: This isn't possible since SASS variables work so that they change the variable in the current block, and not outside. Also, if it would work in the way you would want it to work, it would still output with 2 different classes because of limitations in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for reply @jeroenvisser101 So do you have any idea how to do it in a different way to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: 2 classes with 2 different property values will always end up being outputted as 2 selectors in CSS. You can only group classes when they'll end up to have the same value for 1 property. You can use loops in your SASS code to clean up the code you're working in, but the code that's being served to your users will always have 2 selectors.

Comment: It might be helpful to use a online converter to see the output that's generated when SASS converts it to CSS, to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your pen and made a couple of small adjustments.

My approach here is this:

Don't reset `$activeColor` to a new color, it's just not necessary. What you do instead of set `$user` and `$admin` directly, skipping the setting on `$activeColor`. When you set the background color to the div, set the color as well.

```
.panel-user {
    background-color : darken( $user, 20% );
    color: $user;
}

.panel-admin {
    background-color : darken( $admin, 20% );
    color: $admin;
}
```

Then in your pen where you are setting colors, change them to inherit. So your saying, "Admin background is a darker shade of lightBlue, and the color is lightBlue. Now text stuff inside of `.panel`, inherit your color from the parent."

```
.panel {
    a {
        color : inherit;
    }
}
```

This should illustrate what I mean, http://codepen.io/maxinacube/pen/bpOXyX?editors=0100

Also, it's best not to get too specific on your selectors. After setting the color on the parent item, the span and .good-bye actually inherit the color by default. So all you really need to force inheriting the style is the `a`. Of course, this may change depending on what other styles creep up as you develop but it's best to keep things simple so you're not making diesel selectors or using `!important` to overwrite things in the future.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @maxinacube. That's exactly the solution I was looking for. I tried inherit but in a different way, with the assistant variable. It's basically perfect for me this solution, I knew that it was possible to do it and save a lot of duplicated code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use array of colors, and set individual color while looping this array:

```
$colors: red, blue, orange;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  .color-#{$i} {
    color: nth($colors, $i)
  }
}

.color-1, .color-2 {
  color: #000;
}
```

It will compiles in:

```
.color-1 {
  color: red;
}

.color-2 {
  color: blue;
}

.color-3 {
  color: orange;
}

.color-1, .color-2 {
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Hi @t1m0n thanks for reply, but it strict necessary to have both classes with the comma in the code, like this " .class-1, .class-2 ".

Comment: @AlejandroLora you could also add this rule to the loop. Its not very clear what you are trying to achieve. In your example your previous rules are overrode by `.color-1, color-2 {...}`

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, I think with the example I created, it will be clearer. thanks for your time